# Union of cell array of cells

Tags: string, matlab, cell, union

I'm looking for the way to do the union of two cell arrays of cell arrays of strings. For example:

```
A = {{'one' 'two'};{'three' 'four'};{'five' 'six'}};
B = {{'five' 'six'};{'seven' 'eight'};{'nine' 'ten'}};
```

And I'd like to get something like:

```
C = {{'one' 'two'};{'three' 'four'};{'five' 'six'};{'seven' 'eight'};{'nine' 'ten'}};
```

But when I use `C = union(A, B)` MATLAB returns an error saying:

> Input A of class cell and input B of class cell must be cell arrays of strings, unless one is a string.

Does anyone know how to do something like this in a hopefully simple way? I'd greatly appreciate it.

ALTERNATIVE: A way to have a cell array of separated strings in any other way than a cell array of cell array of strings would be also useful, but as far as I know, it's not possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of a cell array of cell arrays of strings, you can use an m-times-n cell array of strings. If all rows don't have the same number of columns (though in your example they do), you could fill with empty strings. Using an m-times-n cell array can perhaps simplify what you want to do. Even better would be to use a single string per row, formed by individual strings with a separator (reserved character). Then you could use `union`

Comment: I had to modify my other functions to work like this, but I think that was actually the best solution! Thank you! I tried this after implementing Daniel's code and realizing that it considers {'one' 'two'} equal to {'two' 'one'}, which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C=[A;B]    
allWords=unique([A{:};B{:}])
F=cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)(ismember(allWords,x{1})+2*ismember(allWords,x{2}))',C,'uni',false))
[~,uniqueindices,~]=unique(F,'rows')

C(sort(uniqueindices))
```

What my code does: it builds up a list of all words `allwords`, then this list is used to build up a matrix which contains the correlation between the rows and which word they contain. 1=Match for first wird, 2=Match for second word. Finally, on this numeric matrix `unique` can be applied to get the indices.

Including my update, now the 2 words per cell is hardcoded. To get rid of this limitation it would be neseccary to replace the anonymous function (`@(x)(ismember(allWords,x{1})+2*ismember(allWords,x{2}))`) with a more generic implementation. Probably using cellfun again.

Comment: This would work great, but it considers {'one' 'two'} the same as {'two' 'one'}. Sorry for not specifying that this shouldn't happen. Great idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

`Union` doesn't seem like compatible for cell arrays of cells. So, we need to look for some workaround.

One approach would be to get the data from A and B concatenated vertically. Then, along each column assign each cell of strings an unique ID. Those IDs can then be combined into a double array that opens up the possibility of  of using unique with 'rows' option to get us the desired output. This is precisely achieved here.

```
%// Slightly complicated input for safest verification of results
A = {{'three' 'four'};
    {'five' 'six'};
    {'five' 'seven'};
    {'one' 'two'}};

B = {{'seven' 'eight'};
    {'five' 'six'};
    {'nine' 'ten'};
    {'three' 'six'};};

t1 = [A ; B] %// concatenate all cells from A and B vertically
t2 = vertcat(t1{:}) %// Get all the cells of strings from A and B

t22 = mat2cell(t2,size(t2,1),ones(1,size(t2,2)));
[~,~,row_ind] = cellfun(@(x) unique(x,'stable'),t22,'uni',0)
mat1 = horzcat(row_ind{:})

[~,ind] = unique(mat1,'rows','stable')
out1 = t2(ind,:) %// output as a cell array of strings, used for verification too
out = mat2cell(out1, ones(1,size(out1,1)),size(out1,2)) %//desired output
```

Output -

```
out1 = 
    'three'    'four' 
    'five'     'six'  
    'five'     'seven'
    'one'      'two'  
    'seven'    'eight'
    'nine'     'ten'  
    'three'    'six'
```